# How to append multi line template string in div?

Tags: javascript, string, template-strings

I have a template string as follows:

```
var temp = `
for i in range(10):
    print i`
```

What I expect is that this template code should appear in between the div.
My div in index.html is:

```
<div id = "code" style="height:500px;top:0;border: 1px solid black;"></div>
```

My javascript code that trigger append is:

```
$('#code').append(temp);
```

My desired output is:

```
for i in range(10):
        print i
```

My output is:

```
for i in range(10):print i
```

Please suggest me some way to get my desired in proper spacing and lines.
I tried `(temp.split('\n')).join('<br>')` it prints the `temp` in separate lines but it doesn't ensure proper spacing. like this:

```
for i in range(10):
print i
```

Comment: use <pre>-tag around the code that shell be formatted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to format text as-is, use the [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) tag.

> The HTML Preformatted Text () represents preformatted text. Text within this element is typically displayed in a non-proportional font exactly as it is laid out in the file. Whitespaces inside this element are displayed as typed.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use a CSS property called [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

This allows you to put your `div` to work like a `pre` or `code` tag.

```
#code {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```